# 2 commands on single button

Tags: ms-access, button, command

I have a button, and on the button I’m currently using the “DoCmd.OpenForm” command, but would also like the same button to clear the table contents from the previous user on single click. Is this possible?

The button is a Begin button, and once the member clicks begin it will take them to another form to complete, but I want it to clear table contents on the same click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the code that the Access Wizard has created to have as many commands as you want. In this case, the code should look like:

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM [Table1];"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form13"
End Sub
```

Regards,